# How can I setup a instance EC2 with docker and access it with the IP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, docker, docker-compose

I've setup a docker-compose project in a Instance but I don't know how to access from my IP or public dns (ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com), this is part of my docker-compose file

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/web # This name have to be the same like the WORKDIR in your Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  links:
    - redis
  environment:
```

this is my security group

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can access as expected on localhost:8080 inside the ec2 instance? If so then do you need to configure the ec2 instance firewall to open port 8080?

Comment: but, for example with only a docker container I can access without problems but with docker-compose I cant do it... this is a simple example: docker run -d -p 80:5000 training:latest python app.py

Comment: Mmmm I suggest ensuring that the environment is suitable for compose, try bringing up a simple web server using compose using the NGINX image and see if u can access the url within the ec2 instance on localhost

Comment: Compose should only be doing what docker does